# Terraform output defined are empty

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

I am making use of modules. And this is the structure of my files - 
 modules

```
main.tf  
|--module1
|     |--main.tf
|     |--outputs.tf
|     |--variables.tf
|
|--module2
|     |--main.tf
|     |--outputs.tf
|     |--variables.tf
```

I have a main.tf file which runs two modules. When i run *terraform output* command it is expected to return the outputs instead it returns - "The state file either has no outputs defined, or all the defined
outputs are empty. Please define an output in your configuration
with the `output` keyword and run `terraform refresh` for it to
become available. If you are using interpolation, please verify
the interpolated value is not empty"

I would want to know why is this happening?

Comment: You need to redefine the outputs at the "root" level as well. I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/48091472/2291321

Comment: I am making use of remote state too

Comment: What difference does that make?

Comment: Oh okay. Just thought it might affect.

Comment: So, does this mean after i declare a module block, i have to mention the output block too?\

Comment: Yes. I've closed this question as a duplicate for now but if there's something I've missed that means this isn't a duplicate of the linked question then let me know and edit the question to show why this isn't a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR i have changed the question a bit. Hope that helps..your solution was about nested modules. I dont think i am using nested modules in here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212618/discussion-between-siddhimorajkar-and-ydaetskcor).